# Can't import function from user module

Tags: python, function, module, directory

My project is as following

```
project/
    utils.py
    __init__.py 
    my_folder/
        notebook.ipynb
```

In my notebook, I'm trying to import a function `func` with `from project.utils import func` but I get `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'project'`

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

```
import sys, os
sys.path.append(os.getcwd()) # Adding path to this module folder into sys path    
from project.utils import func
```

or

```
from .project.utils import func
```

or

```
from .utils import func
```

or

```
from project import utils
```

Comment: First option gives
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'project'

second gives
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package

third gives
SyntaxError: invalid syntax